# Sticky sidebar doesn't scroll

Tags: jquery, sidebar, sticky

I have an issue, I'm using stickem jquery plugin you can find it here:
https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

The issue is that when its working fine offline, but when I uploaded it online, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?!

here is a page of the website:
http://aldeekdesign.com/the%20mena%20tech.html

Comment: try to specify where it doesn't work...

Comment: on chrome and safari its not working all the time, it depends, sometimes it work and some other times it doesn't work.

for example on the link i posted for my website: 
you will find a text next to an image with a title (Home page layout) it should scroll all the time, but sometimes it doesn't and I found out that when it doesn't I can make it work by scaling the size of the browser then scrolling again it works.